# auto delete of documents is not working in Apache Solr

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, solr4

I am using Apache Solr 7 and trying to automate deletion of documents. I've done following steps as per Lucene's documentation.

step 1. in solrschema.xml

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain default="true"> 
<processor class="solr.processor.DocExpirationUpdateProcessorFactory"> 
  <int name="autoDeletePeriodSeconds">30</int> 
  <str name="ttlFieldName">time_to_live_s</str> 
  <str name="expirationFieldName">expire_at_dt</str> 
</processor> 
<processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" /> 
<processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
```

step 2. in managed-schema.xml

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="time_to_live_s" type="string" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="expire_at_dt" type="date" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

step 3. I created a core by name sample1 and add the following document

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/sample1/update?commit=true' -d '[{ "id":"sample_doc_1","expire_at_dt":"NOW+10SECONDS"}]'
```

after 10 Seconds, the document is still there. Am i missing any of the step, here or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: First of all - the `autoDeletePeriodSeconds` value tells Solr how often it should remove documents that have expired, so in this case documents can be present for up to 40 seconds. The `expire_at_dt` should probably also be just  `+10SECONDS` (and not NOW+...). Are you getting any values in the `expire_at_dt` field?

Comment: Sir, if i just add `+10SECONDS` it gives out error as, `Invalid date string: +10SECONDS`. Also, I'm getting `2017-10-05T16:46:22.049Z` for`expire_at_dt` field @MatsLindh

Answer (score 1):

I think in the indexing you should set the field `time_to_live_s` not the `expire_at_dt`, and value `+10SECONDS` or whatever you want will be fine.

As a reference:

> ttlFieldName - Name of a field this process should look for in each
>   document processed, defaulting to *ttl*. If the specified field name
>   exists in a document, the document field value will be parsed as a
>   Date Math Expression relative to NOW and the result will be added to
>   the document using the expirationFieldName. Use  to disable this feature.

If you want to directly set the expiration date - you should set the proper date string, not the Date Math Expression.

I have full working example of the auto delete code [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene5/src/main/scala/org/mystic/AutoDelete.scala)